# Filament (V2) widget table action not working as expected

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have the following widget table in Filament V2. The tooltip works correctly and shows the right record but when i click the button the $record is always the top record in the table. All i can find in the documentation that might help is is [this](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/widgets#accessing-the-current-record) but when i add $this->record remains null after i click the action. Not sure if i need to set this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\PlanResource\Widgets;

use App\Model;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Widgets\TableWidget as BaseWidget;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class TestWidget extends BaseWidget
{
    protected int|string|array $columnSpan = 'full';

    protected function getTableQuery(): Builder
    {
        return Model::whereDate('date', '=', now())
    }

    protected function getTableColumns(): array
    {
        return [
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name'),
        ];
    }

    protected function getTableActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Tables\Actions\Action::make('run')
                ->icon('heroicon-o-lightning-bolt')
                ->tooltip(fn (Model $record): string => $record->name)
                ->action(function (Model $record): void {
                    $a = $record;
                }),
        ];
    }
}
```